# Check Which operating system is installed ( CentOS, Ubuntu, Redhat, ... etc)

Tags: linux, operating-system

I have been given a server with OS installed. I want to check which Operating system is installed in it. I have used uname -a with ouput of 
    Linux ctl 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Aug 10 09:44:54 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Any suggestions ?

Comment: try `cat /etc/*release`

Answer (score 3):

You could use the /etc/os-release file, which contains information on the os using the freedesktop spec.

Printing out just the OS name and version:

```
awk -F '=' '/PRETTY_NAME/ { print $2 }' /etc/os-release
```

Comment: awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `/etc/os-release' for reading (No such file or directory)

Comment: also 'cat /etc/system-release' may work if that file is available

Answer (score 1):

Using os-release file available in Linux:
cat /etc/os-release

Answer (score 0):

on many OS's, you can get the os via:

lsb_release -d

Comment: lsb package musty be installed then.  on redhat, the package can be added via 'yum install redhat-lsb'

Answer (score 0):

The `el6` in the kernel version could indicate a RedHat (thus Fedora as well), Oracle, Centos, Scientific Linux. Potentially others as well.

At least on some of these systems (others as well) the distribution can be identified from the `/etc/issue*` files. For example:

```
> ls -la /etc/issue*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 57 Oct 22  2014 /etc/issue
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 55 Oct 22  2014 /etc/issue.net
> cat /etc/issue
Welcome to openSUSE 13.2 "Harlequin" - Kernel \r (\l).
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this command to check all detail related to operating system version:

```
cat /etc/*elease
```